# Node CLI: eval file then eval command line argument

Tags: node.js

I can execute a file with

```sh
node ./my-file.js
```

and I can execute some code with `-e`

```sh
node -e 'console.log("hello world")'
```

Is there a way to eval a file and then execute some JavaScript using the variables/functions defined in that file?

I also tried this

```sh
node -e 'const variables = require("./my-file.js"); console.log(variables)'
```

but `./my-file.js` doesn't have `export` statements, it just defines the variables and I don't want to modify it. Right now I'm just firing up a Node REPL, running `.load my-file.js` and then pasting the code I want to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is to load file as pure text, then `eval` it to populate the state.
On Windows 10 I tested it:

```
node -e "fs.readFile('./my-file.js', 'UTF-8', (e,d)=>{eval(d); console.log('age', age, ageOfMe()) })"
```

Output:

```
my file done
age 30 41
```

and `my-file.js` is:

```js
var name = 'John';
var age = 30;
function ageOfMe(){
  return age + 11;
}
console.log('my file done');
```